# What is the best way to run kubectl in GoCD task?

Tags: go-cd

I'm looking at GoCD as a pipeline/delivery tool for deploying Kubernetes applications to multiple clusters.

Currently stuck at a very basic question: What is the recommended way to run `kubectl` command in a GoCD task?

Do I create a custom GoCD agent image with kubectl installed? Are there any plugins that can facilitate this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't gotten any responses yet: Yes, you will need to have `go-agent` and `kubectl` installed on the same machine, or in the same container.

See the [documentation for installing go-agent](https://docs.gocd.org/current/installation/installing_go_agent.html), and the [docker elastic agents plugin](https://github.com/gocd-contrib/docker-elastic-agents-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I used Dockerfile for do that. For work with GCP, but you can remove the "gcloud" section if you don't use it.

```
FROM gocd/gocd-agent-alpine-3.9:v19.12.0

USER root

# begin - gcloud
RUN \
  apk add --update make ca-certificates openssl python && \
  update-ca-certificates && \
  wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
  tar zxf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
  ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false && \
  ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --quiet components update && \
  rm -f google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
# end - gcloud

# begin - kubectl
RUN apk update && apk add curl git
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.1/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod u+x kubectl && mv kubectl /bin/kubectl
# end - kubectl

# begin - docker
RUN apk add docker
# end - docker

USER go
ENV PATH $PATH:/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```